# C#/.net equivalent of android handler

Tags: c#, java, android, .net

I am looking for equivalent functionality in c#/.NET environment as android.os.handler where I can post work to a single thread to be executed in order. I have come across with some ActionBlock type of constructs for this purpose but I rather not use .NET 4.5 and accomplish this with lower versions.

Note: The reason I'm not using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkıtem() is obvious. It's not synchronous by it's nature. This is my first post here, sorry if I did any mistake.

Comment: you could potentially roll your own using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx It has events for when the work is completed... so you would know to queue up the next item.  Not ideal obviously.. but could get you there.

Comment: yo can have a look also on https://rx.codeplex.com/ (reactive framework) that has for sure that kind of stuff already implemented: threading in chain.

Answer (score 1):

In Java there is the [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) interface for handling tasks. It does exactly what you want when using [Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29).

Searching for an equivalent in C# brought me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661760/c-sharp-equivalent-for-java-executorservice-newsinglethreadexecutor-or-how-t) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928018/is-there-a-net-equivalent-to-java-util-concurrent-executor).

Comment: For scheduling tasks at specific time/delay, use `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()`

Answer (score 0):

```
SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(_ => {
    // body
}, null);
```